# R Programming: Evaluating an expression when objects exist in multiple environments

Tags: r

**Short Version**

An expression with two variables, `x` and `y`, where `x` is contained in environment 1
and `y` is contained in a second environment.  How does the programmer evaluate
the expression?

**Detailed Version**

I have a function that takes a `formula` and data.frame as arguments.  On the
the right hand side of the `formula` is a call to the function `splines::bs` to
generate a B-spline basis.  The workhorse function does a few things, one of
which requires extracting the `bs` call from the formula and evaluating it.  The
problem I am trying to solve involves evaluating the `bs` call when argument
values are contained in different environments.

Here are the functions needed to recreate the issue I am working on

```
library(splines)

extract_bmat <- function(form) { 
  B <- NULL
  rr <- function(x) { 
    if (is.call(x) && grepl("bs", deparse(x[[1]]))) { 
      B <<- x 
    } else if (is.recursive(x)) { 
      as.call(lapply(as.list(x), rr))
    } else {
      x
    }
  } 
  z <- lapply(as.list(form), rr)
  B
}

some_workhorse <- function(formula, data) { 
  # ... lots of cool stuff ... 
  # fit <- lm(formula, data) 

  bmat <- eval(extract_bmat(formula), data)
  bmat
}

# The following works when evaluated in the .GlobalEnv
# The eval(extract_bmat(formula), data) call within the some_workhorse
# function works without errors
xi      <- c(3, 4.5)
eg_data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = sin(1:10)) 
some_workhorse(y ~ bs(x, knots = xi), data = eg_data)
```

Now, if the function `some_workhorse` and the `xi` vector and `eg_data`
`data.frame` are generated within a function environment causes an error.

```
foo <- function() { 
  xi_in_foo      <- c(2, 3)
  eg_data_in_foo <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = sin(1:10)) 

  some_workhorse(y ~ bs(x, knots = xi_in_foo), data = eg_data_in_foo)
}

foo()
# Error in sort(c(rep(Boundary.knots, ord), knots)) :
#   object 'xi_in_foo' not found
```

The location of the error is within the `splines::bs` call, but that is not the
important part; `xi_in_foo` not found is the important issue to address.

I know the issue is related to my poor handling of environments in R.  My
primary question is

- How should the call `eval(extract_bmat(formula), data)` within the
  `some_workhorse` function be written so that it works correctly when called in
  the `.GlobalEnv` or when called within a function environment?

Secondary question:

- Within the `extract_bmat` function, I would prefer to define an environment
  for `B` and use `assign` instead of `<<-`.  I suspect that `<<-` is the best
  option because of the uncertainty in the levels of recursion taking place.
  That said, I would like to see other solutions.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your function as

```
some_workhorse <- function(formula, data) { 
  # ... lots of cool stuff ... 
  # fit <- lm(formula, data) 

  bmat <- eval(extract_bmat(formula), data, environment(formula))
  bmat
}
```

Note that `formula`s in R capture the environment in which they were created. As long as `xi_in_foo` exists in the environment where the formula was defined, this should work. Variables will first be looked up in the `data` list/data.frame and then the formula environment would be used as the enclosing environment. If you weren't using formula,s sometimes people use `parent.frame()` as the `enclos=` parameter so that variables are looked for in the environment in which the function was called, rather than were the function was defined as is the default with R's lexical scoping.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the explanation.  I had tried using the parent.frame() as the enclosure with no success.   I appreciate the time you've taken to answer this question and others.